# ¿Por qué es que este código funciona? Unique in Order

Tags: python

Quisiera saber por qué este código sí funciona a pesar de que en ninguna parte convierte los caracteres a mayúscula. El código es un reto de Code Wars, Unique in order. El reto dice así:

Implement the function unique_in_order which takes as argument a sequence and returns a list of items without any elements with the same value next to each other and preserving the original order of elements.

For example:

```
unique_in_order('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
unique_in_order('ABBCcAD')         == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'c', 'A', 'D']
unique_in_order([1,2,2,3,3])       == [1,2,3]
```

El código dice así:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    result = []
    prev = None
    for i in iterable:
        if i != prev:
            result.append(i)
        prev = i

    return result
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El código no se trata de convertir nada a mayúsculas o viceversa. Si no que dice que recibirá como entrada un iterable (cadena, lista, tupla) y retornará una lista con el mismo orden de los elementos de entrada, pero omitiendo las repeticiones consecutivas. De hecho en la segunda lista hay un 'Cc' y ambos forman parte de la lista de salida.
En la misma función dejo explicado en comentarios:

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    result = [] # Se inicializa una lista
    prev = None # Esta variable contendrá el valor anterior
    for i in iterable: # El valor actual es cada elemento del iterable por cada ciclo
        if i != prev: # Si el elemento actual es diferente del valor anterior
            result.append(i) # Añadirlo a la lista
        prev = i # Se asigna a la variable del valor anterior, el elemento actual
        # Siguiente iteración del for

    return result # Cuando termine el for, se retorna la lista resultante
```